# Dependency Injection when using the Command Pattern

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, command-pattern

I'm using the Command Pattern for the first time. I'm a little unsure how I should handle dependencies.

In the code below, we dispatch a `CreateProductCommand` which is then queued to be executed at a later time. The command encapsulates all the information it needs to execute.

In this case it is likely we will need to access a data store of some type to create the product. My question is, how do I inject this dependency into the command so that it can execute?

```
public interface ICommand {
    void Execute();
}

public class CreateProductCommand : ICommand {
    private string productName;

    public CreateProductCommand(string productName) {
        this.ProductName = productName;
    }

    public void Execute() {
        // save product
    }
}

public class Dispatcher {
    public void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand {
        // save command to queue
    }
}

public class CommandInvoker {
    public void Run() {

        // get queue

        while (true) {
            var command = queue.Dequeue<ICommand>();
            command.Execute();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}

public class Client {
    public void CreateProduct(string productName) {
        var command = new CreateProductCommand(productName);
        var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        dispatcher.Dispatch(command);
    }
}
```

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After looking at your code I would recommend not using the command pattern, but instead using command data objects and a command handler:

```
public interface ICommand { }

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class CreateProductCommand : ICommand { }

public class CreateProductCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> {
    public void Handle(CreateProductCommand command) {

    }
}
```

This scenario is more suitable for cases where CreateProductCommand might need to cross application boundaries. Also, you can have an instance of CreateProductCommand resolved by a DI container with all dependencies configured. The dispatcher, or 'message bus' would invoke the handler when it receives the command.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658117.aspx#MessageBusStyle) for some background info.

Comment: thanks for that. The CQRS folk on twitter had also pointed me in this direction.

Comment: And even without CQRS, a design as stated above has great benefits. Here's an [informative article about this pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).